# Image.FromFile File Not Found

Tags: c#, image

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace BurgerShop.Models
{
    public class FoodDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<FoodContext>
    {
        public byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image image)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        protected override void Seed(FoodContext context)
        {
            Burger hamburger = new Burger
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Гамбургер",
                Price = 49,
                Image = ImageToByteArray(Image.FromFile("BurgerShop\\Content\\img\\Burgers\\1.jpg"))
            };
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to read the image from file I have `FileNotFoundException`. I have that image in my file path, so it's strange that compiler can't find a file. Help me please!

Comment: What do you expect us to say? The file isn't where you think it is.

Comment: ask this same question to yourself and see if you can answer it with the provided information? If not then how do you expect it from others?

Comment: Is the folder BurgerShop in the Debug or Release folder of you project?

Comment: The file is in location that i matched in Image.FromFile(), but compiler answered me by File Not Found Exception, so that is my problem.

Comment: No, folder BurgerShop is already name of my project.

Comment: _FromFile("BurgerShop_  that is a path __relative to the project__ . usually a bad idea.

Comment: Does the filename contains an absolute path, or relative? Consider the following: whenever you start a project from Visual Studio, the current folder is the solution folder. Whenever you start externally, the current folder is the executable file folder.

Comment: _"compiler answered me by `FileNotFoundException`"_ -- doubtful. The compiler doesn't emit errors like that. More likely, the exception was thrown at runtime, and for the usual reason: the file isn't where you said it is.

Comment: in which folder is your *.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Burger hamburger = new Burger
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Гамбургер",
            Price = 49,
            Image = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Content\\img\\Burgers\\1.jpg")))
        };
```

I already found the answer and it works, thank you to everyone, who have participated in my problem)

Answer (score 0):

try changing the address to complete address instead of relative.

```
Image.FromFile("C:\\..\\BurgerShop\\Content\\img\\Burgers\\1.jpg")
```

Also consider finding the full path using

```
fullPath = Path.GetFullPath("\\BurgerShop\\Content\\img\\Burgers\\1.jpg");
var image= Image.FromFile(fullpath);
```

Comment: Sorry, don't get what I should do with `fullPath`?

Answer (score 0):

since you seem to use a relative path I would suggest to go from the folder where your *.exe is situated.

So if you are running a debug session your exe will be in ..bin\Debug\ then this might work:

```
Image = ImageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(@"..\..\Content\img\Burgers\1.jpg"))
```

If you have the executable somewhere else you should copy you Content folder in the same folder as the *.exe of your programm. And make sure that your *.jpg file is also there. (checking whether it is *.jpeg or *.jpg would also help)

then you could just use the relative path:

```
Image = ImageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(@"Content\img\Burgers\1.jpg"))
```

Comment: I don't know why but it isn't work too, even when I put my images in bin folder

Comment: By the way, if i want to use Image.FromFile() I have strict store my Content folder in bin folder? In two words what I exactly want by this code: I use asp.net mvc and I have a database, so i want initialize some info in Database Table filed, and also put an image converted in byte array. Easy, but the stupid problem - FileNotFoundException, maybe it is another ways to take my image from folder?

Comment: @AnthonyGorshenin could you post the full path of where your *.exe is and the full path of where your 1.jpg is?