# System.io.filenotfoundexception image not found after installation

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I created a WPF app using c# in which I have ContextMenuStrip with images..
I am using custom action to launch my application after installation..
As App launches first time it gives me exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException

[image]

but when it is launched manually by double clicking desktop icon no exception is raised and works fine and all images are shown..
here's code of using image..

```
titleMenuItem.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("setting.ico")
```

but when I run application in visual studio no exception is raised..
and I am using visual studio installer if it matters..

**What I have tried:**

I tried putting the images in **bin/debug** folder of project and in **Application Folder** of setup..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image.FromFile File Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817660/image-fromfile-file-not-found)

Comment: I will try try 2 things:
1. Change path to full path (like C:\setting.ico) and try then
2. Generate message box with current path and see if it's the same in both application runs.

Comment: but i am getting image when app is launched second time..